# Error: Unexpected type ZodUnion when parsing data with prisma-zod-generator in Remix

Tags: node.js, prisma, remix.run, zod

I tried adding a the Prisma generator [Prisma Zod Generator](https://github.com/omar-dulaimi/prisma-zod-generator) to my Remix project but I am struggling a bit with understanding how it is supposed to be applied, especially when updating a model. I have a custom model `TextContent` defined as such:

```
model TextContent {
  content   Content @relation(fields: [contentId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  contentId String  @id
  text      String
}
```

And I also have the generated schema `TextContentUncheckedUpdateInputObjectSchema`.

I am now trying to create an action function where I validate the input via the generated schema. I understood that the zod schema `parse` method won't work directly on the `FormData` object that comes from `request`, so I made use of [Remix Params Helper](https://github.com/kiliman/remix-params-helper) which offers a convenient helper method `getFormDataOrFail` where you simply put in the request and the zod schema object to get the parsed data:

```
export async function action({ request, params }: ActionArgs) {
  const data = await getFormDataOrFail(request, TextContentUncheckedUpdateInputObjectSchema)
  await prisma.textContent.update({
    data,
    where: {
      contentId: params.contentId
    }
  });
  return null;
}
```

The problem now is that I get an error message when trying to parse the data:

```
Error: Unexpected type ZodUnion for key contentId
    at processDef (my-app/node_modules/remix-params-helper/dist/cjs/helper.js:179:15)
    at processDef (my-app/node_modules/remix-params-helper/dist/cjs/helper.js:162:9)
    at parseParams (my-app/node_modules/remix-params-helper/dist/cjs/helper.js:36:9)
    at getParamsInternal (my-app/node_modules/remix-params-helper/dist/cjs/helper.js:54:9)
    at getFormDataOrFail (my-app/node_modules/remix-params-helper/dist/cjs/helper.js:120:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at action (my-app/app/routes/contents.$contentId.tsx:12:15)
    at Object.callRouteActionRR (my-app/build/server.js:39649:20)
    at callLoaderOrAction (my-app/build/server.js:38772:20)
    at submit (my-app/build/server.js:38365:20)
```

And this is where I get confused. Why does it say I'm supplying a `ZodUnion` type as value for `contentId`?

I've double-checked the key/values being sent in the `FormData` object and they are valid (`contentId` and `text` in the `FormData` object maps to `string` values). Note that `contentId` is sent both via params and in the `FormData` object.

Comment: Hi. `remix-params-helper` doesn't handle *all* Zod schemas. `ZodUnion` happens to be one of the items it doesn't handle. Can you create an issue in the repo with the schema? Thanks!

Comment: @Kiliman Seems like there already is [a related issue](https://github.com/kiliman/remix-params-helper/issues/34) regarding it. Although it addresses `ZodIntersection` it mentions `ZodUnion` as well.